# before_create not invoked when object created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sequel

I have a Lease Model:

```
class Lease < Sequel::Model
    def before_create
        self.issued_date = DateTime.now
        self.return_date = DateTime.now + 2.weeks
        super
    end
end
```

User Model:

```
class User < Sequel::Model
    many_to_many :items, left_key: :user_id, right_key: :item_id,
                 join_table: :leases
end
```

and Item Model:

```
class Item < Sequel::Model
    many_to_many :users, left_key: :item_id, right_key: :user_id,
                 join_table: :leases
end
```

My lease model has `user_id` and `item_id` as foreign keys.

When I create a Lease object the `issued_date` and `return_date` are created and saved in the database,  but, when I assign a user with an item, a lease object is created but `before_create` is not invoked resulting in `issued_date` and `return_date` set to nil.

Comment: Can you please describe a bit more, how you assign `user_id` and `item_id` into `lease` model ?

Comment: What is `many_to_many`? Do you mean `has_and_belongs_to_many`? Or does this come from some kind of gem, or your own code?

Comment: I am using Sequel. https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel  @nathanvda

Comment: Ah right: I should have seen that :) I know with `has_and_belongs_to_many` the join-model is implicit, so any code inside (if defined) is ignored. When you use an explicit join-model (using `has_many :through`) in ActiveRecord it does work. You are using an explicit join-model, so I guess this is an oversight/bug/feature in sequel? I hope somebody can give better help.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set your before_create method like this:

```
before_create :before_create_method

def before_create_method
  #method body
end
```